# Camera with Overlay in UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, camera, overlay

currently trying to make a ViewController, which include a Camera with a Overlay. I want to implement a scan function. the camera should show a field where it is scanned and save it then as a picture.

one of you has an idea? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I used this tutorial: http://www.ios-developer.net/iphone-ipad-programmer/development/camera/record-video-with-avcapturesession-2 to create a viewcontroller similar to that. The code a little old but if you make some changes you can easily create a ViewController like that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Github repo, It provides a default view controller with camera view and scan area overlay and it also provides a button to switch between the front and the back cameras.

https://github.com/yannickl/QRCodeReaderViewController